# Need to append multiple header request to QNetworkRequest

Tags: c++, qt

I need to append multiple headers request in `QNetworkRequest`. How can I achieve this?

For example below is my URL and the header required:

> www.abc.com?identifier=13er5t&toolid=aze

where '**identifier**' and '**toolid**' are the header which I need to set to my request.
(I dont want to pass it to the URL as specified in example, need to set it in the header)

How do I set this in **`QNetworkRequest`**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("www.abc.com"));
request.setRawHeader("identifier", "13er5t");
request.setRawHeader("toolid", "aze");
```

The headers are not standard HTTP headers, hence it is required to use  `setRawHeader()`. `setHeader()` could be used if it was one of these standard headers:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qnetworkrequest.html#KnownHeaders-enum

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.